# Looping through XML Document

Tags: c#, xml

My Method:

```
if (File.Exists( @"C:\config.xml"))
   {
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xd = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    xd.Load( @"C:\config.xml");
    System.Xml.XmlElement root = xd.DocumentElement;
    System.Xml.XmlNodeList nl = root.SelectNodes("/config");
    foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode xnode in nl)
    {
        string name = xnode.Name;
        string value = xnode.InnerText;
        string nv = name + "|" + value;
        Send(nv);
        }
```

My Xml Doc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<config>
<bla>D</bla>
<def>300</def>
<ttOUT>34000</ttOUT>
<num>3800</num>
<pw>help</pw>
<err>1</err>
....and so on
</config>
```

Now my method returns the first 2 and nothing else. 
What am i doing wrong...

Comment: You say it returns the first two, you mean `<bla>` and `<def>`?

Comment: you are probably pointing an unsaved test file...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`use` the `System.Xml` namespace to avoid long type qualifications ie...

```
    using System.Xml;
```

Then try something like this..

```
    XmlNodeList nl = xd.SelectNodes("config");
    XmlNode root = nl[0];

    foreach (XmlNode xnode in root.ChildNodes)
    {
        string name = xnode.Name;
        string value = xnode.InnerText;
        string nv = name + "|" + value;
        Send(nv);
    }
```

I believe there is something wrong with your method.

a) I don't think `SelectNodes` should take the `/config` argument, rather it should take `config`.

b) After selecting the first (and only - XML files in .Net must have one and only one root node) root node you need to iterate through the `ChildNodes` of the root.

Comment: It's more helpful when you include an explanation of what was wrong with the original code, why that caused the described behavior, and exactly how you fixed it. Throwing up a block of code doesn't make for a much better quality *answer* than it does question.

Comment: @Cody Good point, agreed. Just wanted to get something up there quick as there's some speedy people on this site :) I'll add an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

root is the <config> tag, so I don't understand how root.SelectNodes("/config") should work at all. Use root.Childnodes instead.