# Check if string values appear more than once in document

Tags: c#, loops, duplicates

I have a document (xml) where each line has a format like this

```
<Field ID="{475c2610-c157-4b91-9e2d-6855031b3538}" Name="FullName" DisplayName="Full name" Type="Text" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="FullName" ColName="nvarchar6" Required="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" ReadOnly="FALSE" PITarget="" PrimaryPITarget="" PIAttribute="" PrimaryPIAttribute="" Aggregation="" Node="" />
```

The properties ColName="<>" and ID="{<>}" are supposed to be unique for every line that exists in the document.

How can I loop through each line and and see if the values inside ColName and ID appears more than once(preferrably though C#)?

Comment: Provide a more focused question (i.e. what have you tried) or it is liable to get closed as it is currently too broad. Also arguably a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161223/looping-through-xml-in-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757122/looping-through-xml-document

Answer (score 1):

Treating it like code golf... to get duplicate elements:

```
var duplicateElements = XDocument.Load(pathToDocument).Root.Elements()
                .GroupBy(el => String.Format("{0}|{1}", el.Attribute("ID").Value, el.Attribute("ColName").Value)))
                .Where((val, e) => val.Count() > 1);
```